# Creating Blobstore Photo URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am new to GAE Blostore.... I am trying to display a url of the image uploaded via GAE, but I am having difficulties....any help is appreciated.

1)  The code below displays the key in hex format, which I am not sure why it does that.

2)  Furthermore, how do I get/create an URL to the image with the hex value key?

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

#import os
import urllib
 class UserPhoto(db.Model):
    user = db.StringProperty()
    user1 = db.EmailProperty()
    blob_key = blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty()# blobstore.BlobKey #




class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
       user = users.get_current_user()
       upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
       existing_data = "<br>"






    if user:
        #user_photo = UserPhoto(user=users.get_current_user().email( )
        data = UserPhoto.all()

        results = data.filter('user1 =',user.email())
        rmvStr = len("<__main__.UserPhoto object at ")



        for blob in results:


            existing_data += "Blob item key # : "+ str(blob)[rmvStr:len(str(blob))-1]   +" <br>"
            #existing_data += "Blob item key # : "+ str(blob) +" <br>"


            #self.response.out.write( "value of blob is: " + str(blob))

        self.response.out.write(
            'Hello %s <a href="%s">Sign out</a><br>Is administrator: %s' % 
            (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/"), users.is_current_user_admin())           
            +'<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url+
            """Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
            name="submit" value="Submit"> </form>
            <br>"""+existing_data
        )
    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))


class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
   def post(self):
       upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form

       blob_info = upload_files[0] 
       user = users.get_current_user()

       if user:
           data = UserPhoto()
           data.user1 = user.email()
           data.blob_key = blob_info.key()

           data.put()




         #self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())
         self.redirect('/')

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)



application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                           ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler)],
                          debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to throw a wrench in your entire question here, but you should really consider the Files API.  It's backed by Google Cloud Storage, and the interfaces for accessing are really fast and easy to use.  I'd recommend it over blobstore, especially if you're just getting started on your app.

If you're doing user photos, you could crunch two or three sizes on a taskqueue and toss them up in Cloud Storage probably for cheaper than you can run Blobstore.

Comment: Besides the fact that it's experimental, the files API is not the way you want to be doing this. create_upload_url can write your uploads to GCS if that's what you really want. I have no idea why you think GCS would be cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  For this project I was asked to use Google App Engine Blobstore....